# Detect timeout in bash pipe

Tags: bash

First we will be ssh into a remote server, then we will check below command.

```bash
tail -f xyz.log | grep 'some keyword'
```

If it doesn't print anything for more than 2 minutes, we can send an alert

Comment: One possible approach: Modify your command so that it terminates after the first `grep` occurs (see the `-m` option of grep, assuming that you have gnu grep), and then use the `timeout` command to monitor the 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a small bash script in the middle of your pipe:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

TIMEOUT=120 # seconds

while read -r -s -t $TIMEOUT line || echo "<error message>" >&2 ; do
    if [ -n "$line" ] ; then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done
```

With this, you could write:

```bash
tail -f xyz.log | ./timeout.sh | grep 'whatever'
```

This is an improved version of the script found at the bottom of [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324213/pass-through-pipe-with-timeout).